# VB - Caesar Cipher emulation

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to emulate Caesar Cipher encryption. The problem is whenever I input "wxyz"
(shifted by `3`) the output is "z{|}". But the expected output should be "zabc".

Anyone knows what to add?

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim plaintext As String = TextBox1.Text
            Dim charArray() As Char = plaintext.ToCharArray
            Dim shift = TextBox2.Text
            Dim character As String
            Dim temp As String
            TextBox3.Text = ""



            If shift <> "" And IsNumeric(shift) Then
                If plaintext = "" Then
                    MsgBox("Please input some plain text")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                If shift > 26 Then
                    MsgBox("Maximum shifts reached. Limit is 26!!")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                For loope = 0 To charArray.Length - 1 Step +1
                    temp = charArray(loope)

                    character = Chr(Asc(temp) + shift)

                    TextBox3.Text += character


                Next
                Exit Sub
            Else
                MsgBox("Input numbers only!!")
            End If


        End Sub
```

Comment: What a nice homework :-)

Comment: actually, it's our midterm project :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you shift an Ascii code you should verify that it does not get greater than 122, which is the Ascii code for the character "z". If you go beyond that point, you will get punctuation marks, symbols and that stuff. Google "ASCII table" and you can easily see it for yourself.

So, to solve your problem, if the Ascii code you get after shifting is greater than 122 you should go back and begin by 97 again, which is the ascii for "a".

So, instead of this:

```
            For loope = 0 To charArray.Length - 1 Step +1
                temp = charArray(loope)
                character = Chr(Asc(temp) + shift)
                TextBox3.Text += character
            Next
```

You should do something like

```
            For loope = 0 To charArray.Length - 1 Step +1
                temp = charArray(loope)
                character = Chr(Asc(temp) + shift)
                ' You substract 26, the whole length of the alphabet
                If character > 122 Then
                   character = character - 26 
                End If
                TextBox3.Text += character
            Next
```

No quite sure that this would be stable if `shift` is greater than 26, but anyhow you already check its value so it should work.

Comment: What about uppercase letters?

Comment: Uppercase letters have different ascii codes. They go from 65 to 90. You should apply the same concept but in a different interval. If you want to have both upper and lowercase letters on your message, before shifting you should check if the original char is lower or upper, and then shift controlling that the resulting char is not greater than 90 (upper) or 122 (lower). On the other hand, if you don't mind the message case, you can use ToUpper() or ToLower() to transform the whole message initially and then handle just one interval.

Comment: "Conversion from string "z{|}" to type integer in not valid." But I got it to work anyway. The only problem I'm working with now is the uppercase. I'm gonna try your suggestion :) Thank you :-)

Comment: yay I did it!! Thank you so much :-D